# Chat messages to print on either side of the screen

Tags: android, xml, listview, custom-adapter

I am trying to mock up of chat application to print senders and receivers messages on either side of the screen.
I have used CustomAdapter and setup two different layouts for server response and user sent messages.
In this mock up every message user sends using the function 'sendMessage()' server response is got 'testRecievServerMessage()' which is called within the sendMessage() function.

and when I run it the UI is always set as server response. How do I fix this to use different layout for user sent messages and server sent messages.

Please guide where I am going wrong.

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Here is my code

list_item.xml - userSent message UI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:weightSum="10">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFrontSpacing"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"></LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvUserMessage"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

list_item_server_response.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:weightSum="10">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvServerMessage"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="7"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llEndSpacing"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Button which sends data

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
         />
```

OnCreate has

```
   ListView lvMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    lvMessages.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

SendMessage and recieve message and custom adapter

```
   public void sendMessage(View v){

    String message = etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
    messages.add(message);
    serverResponse = false;
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    etMessage.setText("");
    testRecievServerMessage();
}

public void testRecievServerMessage(){
    String testServerMessage = "Test";
    messages.add(testServerMessage);
    serverResponse = true;
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int size = messages.size();
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(serverResponse == true){
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_server_response, null);
            TextView tvSingleMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvServerMessage);
            String message = messages.get(position);
            tvSingleMessage.setText(message);
        }else{
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            TextView tvSingleMessage = (TextView) 
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserMessage);
            String message = messages.get(position);
            tvSingleMessage.setText(message);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad..
The boolean value 'serverResponse' was not holding the value as the entire list was re populated.

So instead of using the ArrayList I have used HashMap and ArrayList in combination in which each message has information whether it is a user or server based message.

here is the entire code code for your reference.

```
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import org.w3c.dom.Text;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

public class ChatWindow extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> allMessages = new 
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
HashMap<String, String> hmMessage;
CustomAdapter customAdapter;
EditText etMessage;
FloatingActionButton btnSendMessage;
Boolean serverResponse;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    serverResponse = false;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_window);
    etMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
    btnSendMessage = (FloatingActionButton) 
   findViewById(R.id.btnSendMessage);

    hmMessage = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hmMessage.put("Key_source", "User");
    hmMessage.put("key_message", "Hi");
    allMessages.add(hmMessage);
    hmMessage = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hmMessage.put("Key_source", "Server");
    hmMessage.put("key_message", "Connection established!.. How can I 
   help");
    allMessages.add(hmMessage);
    ListView lvMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    lvMessages.setAdapter(customAdapter);


    etMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
  int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int 
    count) {
            if(s.length() > 0){
                btnSendMessage.setEnabled(true);
            }else{
                btnSendMessage.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
   }

   public void sendMessage(View v){

    String message = etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
    hmMessage = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hmMessage.put("Key_source", "User");
    hmMessage.put("key_message", message);
    allMessages.add(hmMessage);
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    etMessage.setText("");
    testRecievServerMessage();
  }

  public void testRecievServerMessage(){
    String testServerMessage = "Test";
    hmMessage = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hmMessage.put("Key_source", "Server");
    hmMessage.put("key_message", testServerMessage);
    allMessages.add(hmMessage);
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }


    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int size = allMessages.size();
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String source = allMessages.get(position).get("Key_source");
        String message = allMessages.get(position).get("key_message");
        if(source == "Server"){
            convertView = 
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_server_response, null);
            TextView tvSingleMessage = (TextView) 
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvServerMessage);
            tvSingleMessage.setText(message);
        }else{
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, 
    null);
            TextView tvSingleMessage = (TextView) 
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserMessage);
            tvSingleMessage.setText(message);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
      }


     }
```